# Topological manifolds with no differentiable structure

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I’m a beginner to this topic, so please forgive me if this is a silly question.

I am reading the book “An Introduction To Manifolds” by Loring W. Tu and on page 53 it states that a “smooth manifold is a topological manifold with a maximal atlas.” It also goes ahead and proves that “every atlas is contained in a unique maximal atlas.”

**My actual question:**

The book says on page 57 that there are topological manifolds with no differentiable structure (previously defined as a maximal atlas). How can this be true if every atlas for a manifold can be contained in a maximal atlas?

In addition, he says that “$\Bbb{R}^n$ is a smooth manifold with a maximal atlas $(\Bbb{R}^n, r^1, ..., r^n)$ where the $r^n$ are the standard coordinates on $\Bbb{R}^n$.” There are many other charts which are compatible with this one such as $2r^n$, so am I misunderstanding the concept of a maximal atlas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A topological Manifold is a locally euclidean (second countable) hausdorff space. As you see, there is no Atlas required to define a topological Manifold. The point is that in a (smooth) Atlas you require the transition maps to be smooth. The proposition then says, that if you have a (smooth) Atlas $\mathcal{A}$, it is contained in a unique maximal atlas $\mathcal{A}^{\text{max}}$ which contains all charts compatible with $\mathcal{A}$. So if you don't have a smooth Atlas to begin with, you don't get a smooth structure. What Tu means is that there exist topological manifolds which can't be equipped with a smooth structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What about the second question?

Comment: You mean why $(\mathbb{R}^{n}, r^1, ..., r^n)$ is a maximal atlas?

Comment: Yeah, that one.

Comment: I don't think $(\mathbb{R}^n, r^1,...,r^n)$ even is maximal as you can take any diffeomorphism $\phi : U \rightarrow \phi(U)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $((\mathbb{R}^n,r^1,...,r^n),(\phi,U))$ is still an Atlas.

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I thought too…

Comment: If you think about it, it very much makes sense. The intuition behind the maximal atlas is that it contains all suitable 'coordinate systems' on $M$ ($M$ being the Manifold in question). If you are in $\mathbb{R}^n$ you want to be able to use every diffeomorphism in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as local coordinates. So the maximal Atlas contains precisely all the diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: My apologies, accidentally moved to chat. Thanks for the answer!